# Symfony2 form doesn't show any errors yet it doesn't display

Tags: php, symfony

Good day, i have this form in sf2 that it's bine linked to an entity and i'm having trouble solving the issues with it. For start the form get's displayed i write a good amount of text it get's submit if i run a print_r($_POST) in the method from controller it shows me the data i've submited but if i run from inside isValid() i'm not getting anything and i'm not getting any errors from it and that leaves me with no idea what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/papetarie/cautare", name="papetarie_search_form")
 * @Template("CatalogBundle:Default:search_form.html.twig")
 */
public function showSearchFormAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('Keyword', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Cautare Produs',
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'sr-only'),
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Cautare Produs',
                'pattern'     => '.{2,}', //minlength
                'class'       => 'col-md-10'
        ),
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Campul nu poate sa fie gol')),
                new Length(array('min' => 2))
        ),
    ))
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'save btn-primary')))
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
       $data = $form->get('Keyword')->getData();
       print_r($data);
    }


    return array(
        'search_form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

search_form.html.twig

```
{% for label, flashes in app.session.flashbag.all %}
{% for flash in flashes %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
{{ flash }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{{form_start(search_form, {'action': path('papetarie_search_form'), 'method' : 'POST', 'attr': {'id': 'papetarie_search_form', 'class': 'form-inline'} })}}
<div class="input-group col-md-10">
    {{ form_label(search_form.Keyword) }}
    {{ form_errors(search_form.Keyword) }}
    {{ form_widget(search_form.Keyword) }}
</div>
{{ form_widget(search_form._token) }}
{{form_end(search_form)}}
```

The way  that i'm displaying the form

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{ render(controller('CatalogBundle:Default:showSearchForm')) }}
            </div>
```

The output from get_class_methods()

```
array(42) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "__clone"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "getConfig"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "getName"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "getPropertyPath"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "isRequired"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "isDisabled"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "setParent"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "getParent"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "getRoot"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "isRoot"
  [11]=>
  string(7) "setData"
  [12]=>
  string(7) "getData"
  [13]=>
  string(11) "getNormData"
  [14]=>
  string(11) "getViewData"
  [15]=>
  string(12) "getExtraData"
  [16]=>
  string(10) "initialize"
  [17]=>
  string(13) "handleRequest"
  [18]=>
  string(6) "submit"
  [19]=>
  string(4) "bind"
  [20]=>
  string(8) "addError"
  [21]=>
  string(11) "isSubmitted"
  [22]=>
  string(7) "isBound"
  [23]=>
  string(14) "isSynchronized"
  [24]=>
  string(24) "getTransformationFailure"
  [25]=>
  string(7) "isEmpty"
  [26]=>
  string(7) "isValid"
  [27]=>
  string(16) "getClickedButton"
  [28]=>
  string(9) "getErrors"
  [29]=>
  string(17) "getErrorsAsString"
  [30]=>
  string(3) "all"
  [31]=>
  string(3) "add"
  [32]=>
  string(6) "remove"
  [33]=>
  string(3) "has"
  [34]=>
  string(3) "get"
  [35]=>
  string(12) "offsetExists"
  [36]=>
  string(9) "offsetGet"
  [37]=>
  string(9) "offsetSet"
  [38]=>
  string(11) "offsetUnset"
  [39]=>
  string(11) "getIterator"
  [40]=>
  string(5) "count"
  [41]=>
  string(10) "createView"
}
```

the way i dump the errors to see what is the error

```
if(!$form->isValid()) {
    echo "<pre>";
    //var_dump($form->getErrors());
    var_dump(get_class_methods($form));
}
```

if i do

```
var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString());
```

i get

```
string(0) ""
```

While i was still looking for a solution i found something interesting.
if i change the route to /search for example instead of /office/search and i submit the form the form get's the data and works just fine.

Comment: You have to render template in action with form, check out on sf2 cookbook.

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand what you mean :D

Comment: Actually i posted the answer.

Comment: you can also try `$form->getErrorsAsString()` although it as been deprecated. In the twig template you can try `dump(search_form)` as well

Comment: why did i get a -1 when only two people answered the question and i have posted so much info yet no one has any ideas what would be the problem ?  :-(

Comment: it might be a routes issue if `render(controller('CatalogBundle:Default:showSearchForm'))` is in a different file. Try putting the code from search_form.html.twig in the same file as the render method and seeing if it works

Comment: If you need to separate them out later, then maybe use an include instead. I often separate forms into separate form classes instead of creating them in the controller too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action return statement have to be like

```
return $this->render('CatalogBundle:Default:search_form.html.twig', array('search_form' => $form->createView()));
```

Add `exit;` after `print_r`.

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to find template "CatalogBundle:Default:showSearchForm".") in ::ecommerce.html.twig at line 52. I'm getting this error.

Comment: My mistake change showSearchForm to search_form.html.twig

Comment: i noticed  the mistake yet i tested like you said :-D and even if i do it with render at the end i still get the same result ..the form is submited yet nothing from isValid() is not shown.

Comment: So you want to check when it's submitted?

Comment: By the way your form have to be valid to shoot actions in if statement.

Comment: Try post form with exit; after print_r you are actually not stopping after posting just rendering new form.

Comment: well as you can see from the code the form should be valid if i insert asd nothing fancy :D if i'm not wrong :D i know it has to do with the request or with the validation part .. but i can't see the solution :D

Comment: Exit at the end of validation @up.

Comment: i've added after the print_r exit(); same thing form submits everything show s in their place but no dump from isValid()

Comment: So the form is not valid. Make if else statement and var_dump($form->getErrors()); or smth like that if its not this method var_dump(get_class_methods($form));

Comment: the dump on $form->getErrors() doesn't show anything just blank page.